# How should we tag Innocent Life: A Futuristic Harvest Moon?

Tags: discussion, tags

*[Innocent Life: A Futuristic Harvest Moon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Innocent_Life:_A_Futuristic_Harvest_Moon)* is currently tagged as [harvest-moon-innocent](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harvest-moon-innocent), which is less than ideal since it doesn't even follow the right word order. However, there isn't an obvious replacement.

The full name of [innocent-life-a-futuristic-harvest-moon](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/innocent-life-a-futuristic-harvest-moon) is 39 characters, which exceeds the 35 character limit. Cutting out `a-` saves two characters, but that's not enough.

We could truncate it to [innocent-life-a-futuristic-harvest](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/innocent-life-a-futuristic-harvest) (34 chracters), but that takes away the phrase "Harvest Moon", which is the [name of the franchise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Story_of_Seasons) (at the time it was released anyway). It also sounds like a B-movie horror flick from the 80s.

What would be a better way to tag this game?

Comment: Judging from the cover art on Wikipedia, I'd say *'Innocent Life'* is the title with 'A Futuristic Harvest Moon' being more of a subtitle than anything else. While it sucks we can't have both in the tag, I'd suggest simply `[innocent-life]` as the main tag, with other variations e.g. `[harvest-moon-innocent-life]`, `[innocent-life-a-futuristic-harvest]` etc as synonyms. What do you think?

Comment: @Robotnik Good call on it being a subtitle. I would be in favor of your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments above, *'Innocent Life'* is the title with *'A Futuristic Harvest Moon'* being more of a subtitle.

As such, I've changed the tag to [innocent-life](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/innocent-life) with [harvest-moon-innocent-life](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harvest-moon-innocent-life) and [innocent-life-a-futuristic-harvest](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/innocent-life-a-futuristic-harvest) as synonyms.